# Pass Cookie though Ajax Call or use $_COOKIE in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

Is there a specific reason why passing a cookie through an AJAX call would or would not have an impact on performance or maintaining code as opposed to simply calling `$_COOKIE` inside of PHP?

In this case, I use this plugin to get cookies in javascript: [Cookie Plugin](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

Example of passing cookie through Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getCaseManagerReport.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    data: {activeDateSelected: Cookies.get('activeDateSelected').replace(/[+]/g, " "), activeProductSelected: Cookies.get('activeProductSelected')}
})
.done(function(response) {
    //do stuff
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("There was a problem during verification. Please contact your System Administrator...");
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
});
```

});

Then in getCaseManagerReport.php

```
$activeDateSelected = $_POST[‘activeDateSelected’];
```

VS using `$_COOKIE` to retrieve cookie

```
$activeDateSelected = $_COOKIE[‘activeDateSelected’];
```

Comment: What do you mean "passing a cookie through AJAX"?  Cookies can be auto attached to the request by the browser.  Related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Comment: In fact, from a security standpoint, it is preferred if you let the browser handle the attaching of the cookies to the request, and make your responses return the 'httpOnly' header so that javascript cannot access and tamper with your cookies.  Related: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

Comment: I have modified my answer to clarify my question with an example, from your first comment that is.